# Blocks are floating on each other. Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day. Tell me please. Taught django, and took the template html, css, js. There is used bootstrap. Few adapted it for myself. He worked on a 17 '' monitor. Actually, when the 21 'monitor began to look, the blocks ran over each other. Besides, on 15'6, through the phone everything is in order. Tried to attribute in addition to col-sm as col-lg - the result did not. Tell me, please, how can I solve this problem.

It should be - https://i.stack.imgur.com/usEMI.png

How it happened - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvUfX.png

Right-sidebar code:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 page-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="sub-title">
              <h2>Some Notes</h2>
              <a href="джанго код"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a>
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 content-page">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 blog-post">
               <div class="post-title">
                     <a href="джанго код"><h1>джанго код</h1></a>
               </div>
               <div class="post-info">
                     <span>джанго код / by <a href="#" target="_blank">джанго код</a></span>
               </div>
               <p style="word-break: break-all"> джанго код</p>
               <a href="джанго код" class="button button-style button-anim fa fa-long-arrow-right"><span>Read More</span></a>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="load-more-post" class="load-more-button">Load</a>
                    <div id="post-end-message"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Left-sidebar code:

```
<div id="main">
```

```
  <!-- about(left sidebar) -->
  <div class ="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="about-fixed">
    <div class="my-pic">
     <img src="{% static 'images/pic/av-pic.png' %}" alt="av-pic">
    </div>

  <div class="my-detail">
     <div class="white-spacing">
        <h1></h1>
           <span>Learning Web Development</span>
     </div>
        <ul class="social-icon">
            <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="github"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="vk"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></li>
         </ul>
  </div>
```

P.S. Sorry for english.

Comment: is this your complete code? I thought you need to put your col classes inside a row. <div class="row">

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
In this template, there is also a custom css file. I could not find it in it, which can lead to such problems. https://jsfiddle.net/ggdox7we/#&togetherjs=hlbNEATDyN - that custom css.

With wrapping <div "row"> did not work.

Comment: No matter what size of monitor you use. Dimension in pixels does. So you declared .about-fixed { position: fixed; width: 20.8%; }. This declaration changes nature of bootstrap order. Try to remove `position: fixed;` from `.about-fixed ` and add `overflow-y: auto` to `.page-body` selector